# Most effective way to identify which plugin is throwing this error - "An active PHP session was detected"

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

My client's site has a site health tool that is showing this error;

A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.

But it doesn't say which plugin is causing this.

TIA

Comment: deactivate the plugins one after the other

Comment: This question was probably asked because the OP **COULDN'T BELIEVE** that the SUPER SLOW method is REALLY the most effective available. Do you have authoritative expert knowledge that this is indeed the case?